# Manipulating new DOM elements generated through loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, loops, object, dom, settimeout

I'm making this, let's say, game for learning purpose.

**The game is as follows** :

> - There is a chessboard ( this is my grid : array of coordinates )
> - And some, let's call them, ***blobs*** that are moving ***randomly*** on the chessboard.
> - When moving, the ***blobs*** can ***duplicate themselves***.

[image]

**My goal**:

Is to move each ***blob***, one by one, using a ***loop*** and ***setTimeout()***.

**Why setTimeout ?**

Because I don't want them to *move all at the same time on the chessboard*  :)

> **My problem :**
>
> When the ***blob duplicates***, new *DOM elements are injected with Jquery* on the web page. ***But***, the ***loop*** has already finished it's job and ***because of the setTimeout***, the *new DOM elements weren't there when the loop assigned new positions to each blob*.
>
> **The result :**
>
> Only the ***blobs*** that were there at begining of the game ***received there new positions***.

**Sample of my code ( simplified ) :**

```
for (var cycles = 1; cycles <= this.cycles + 1; cycles ++) 
{           
    for (var t = 0; t < CHARACTERS_LIST.length; t++)    // t => Character Type
    {   
        if (CHARACTERS_LIST[t].length != 0) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < CHARACTERS_LIST[t].length; i++)     // i => Index
            {
                    // Moves the blob on the chessboard
                    //
                    // ***********************************************

                    MoveCharacter(t, i);                
            }
        }
    }
}

//********************************************************************

var loop = 1;

function MoveCharacter(t, i){
    CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].moveAndDupicate();    // Duplicates if Math.ramdon succeeds
    LOG.characterHistory();         // Log/Log.js

    setTimeout( function(x, y) { return function() { 
        if (!CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].isBorn) {
            if (x == 0) {

                $('#blue-blob .blob:nth-child(' + (y+1) + ')').css({
                    'top'  : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + 'em',
                    'left' : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + 'em'
                });

            } else if (x == 1) {

                $('#green-blob .blob:nth-child(' + (y+1) + ')').css({
                    'top'  : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + 'em',
                    'left' : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + 'em'
                });

                } else if (x == 2) {

                    $('#red-blob .blob:nth-child(' + (y+1) + ')').css({
                        'top'  : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + 'em',
                        'left' : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + 'em'
                    });

            } else if (x == 3) { 

                $('#special-blob .blob:nth-child(' + (y+1) + ')').css({
                    'top'  : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + 'em',
                    'left' : CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + 'em'
                });
            }
        } else {

            CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].isBorn = false;

            var _blob, _inner;
            _blob  = document.createElement('div');
            _blob.className  = "blob";
            _inner = document.createElement('div');             
            _inner.className = "inner";
            _blob.appendChild(_inner);

            if(CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y] instanceof BlueBlob){
                _inner.style = "background-color:#52DE71;";
                _blob.style  = "top:"  + CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + "em;"
                             + "left:" + CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + "em;";
                $('#blue-blob').append(_blob);
            } else if (CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y] instanceof GreenBlob){
                _inner.style = "background-color:#5299DE;";
                _blob.style  = "top:"  + CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posY + "em;"
                             + "left:" + CHARACTERS_LIST[x][y].posX + "em;";
                $('#green-blob').append(_blob);
            }
        }
    }}(t, i), 100*loop);

    loop++;
}
```

> **So...**:
>
> - Like I said, only the ***blobs*** that were *initially there when the game started*, received new positions.
> - Each ***cycles***, the ***CHARACTERS_LIST[ ]*** is updated.
> - The problem seems to be here : ***.blob:nth-child(' + (y+1) + ')')***, because this element isn't yet created. ( I think... )

I can't seem to find the problem, but I'm sure it's just some minor issues in that code above!

Comment: What does `moveAndDupicate` do? You can try calling that outside the timeout.

Comment: I **edited** my code and called `moveAndDupicate()` ouside the setTimeout function.

I also added a bloc of code at the end of `MoveCharacter` ( which was inside `moveAndDuplicate()` ) and narrowed down the problem a little.

Comment: Now, I'm having another problem, All the _blobs_ moves from first position to the very last position (as if all the setTimeouts fires all at once), but the newly born _blobs_ pops later on (as if the setTimeout worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to acheive all of this using DOM elements and Jquery (not efficient). I used a **html canvas** and all is working fine.